# How can I match the id of two different columns using left outer join in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
select 
    pe.fk_id_produto,
    pe.qt_unitaria,
    er.FK_produto,
    IFNULL(er.quantidade_recebida,0) AS quantidade_recebida
from tblprodutoencomendado as pe 
left outer join tblencomendarecebida er on er.FK_encomenda = pe.FK_num_encomenda  
where fk_id_produto IN(SELECT FK_produto FROM tblencomendarecebida WHERE fk_encomenda = 13) or fk_num_encomenda = 13 
group by fk_id_produto asc;

----------------------------------------------------------------
RESULT OF THIS QUERY

FK_id_produto qt_unitaria FK_produto quantidade_recebida 
------------- ----------- ---------- ------------------- 
13            17          NULL       NULL                   
16            44          13         32                  
15            15          NULL       NULL
20            10          20         10
```

What I desire:

```
FK_id_produto qt_unitaria FK_produto quantidade_recebida 
------------- ----------- ---------- ------------------- 
13            17          13         32 
15            15          NULL       NULL          
16            44          NULL       NULL
20            10          20         10
```

I have tried almost everything... can any one help please? thanks in advance

Comment: hi, to be able to answer you please add how the data shows in each table

Comment: TABLE ON THE LEFT
    FK_id_produto qt_unitaria 
    ------------- -----------
    13            17                 
    16            44                       
    15            15   
    20            10   

 TABLE ON THE RIGHT    
    
    FK_produto quantidade_recebida 
    ------------- ----------- ---------- 
    NULL       NULL             
    NULL       NULL            
    NULL       NULL
    13           32

Answer (score 0):

it looks that your join not on the right field

```
select 
    pe.fk_id_produto,
    pe.qt_unitaria,
    er.FK_produto,
    IFNULL(er.FK_produto,0) AS quantidade_recebida
from tblprodutoencomendado as pe 
left outer join tblencomendarecebida er on er.FK_produto = pe.fk_id_produto
group by fk_id_produto asc;
```

Comment: that's why your join is incorrect, the syntax is okay thats why your query is running and receiving results.

Comment: My original query works, it just does not match up the pe.fk_id_produto and er.fk_produto. Suppose the left pe.fk_id_produto has the value 13, and it spears on the right side too but not in the same line. I would love to match up this er.fk_produto or any other with the ones on the left. I need to match them up cause on the left side i do have quantities and on right i have the received quantities, if i match up both i can then deduct from the ordered quantity the received quantity. Suppose the product id 13 ordered 17 and received 32, but if in the wrong line i can not subtract.

Comment: Ok i tested your code again and it is working the way i want but is not returning the null value or 0 for the missing ids, on contrary it is also bringing the ones on the left. Can it bring the values on left and only the ones that exits on the right but matching up the ids (pe.fk_id_produto, er.fk_produto)?

Comment: try now, i've changed the field in the if

Comment: it does not return zero or null for the none existent fields